# GWT 2.5 causes server (GF 2.1.1) to hang - multiple RPC connections left with CLOSE_WAIT status

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.5, glassfish-2.x

A library upgrade (GWT 2.4.0 -> GWT 2.5.0) was necessary. Unfortunately newer version seems to cause more problems, than it actually solves.

A lot of "dead" connections (hundreds of them) are cumulating on server until it stops to respond. `netstat -na` gives the following result:

```
...
tcp      121      0 10.0.0.5:8181       XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:4609      CLOSE_WAIT
...
```

It occurs only on GWT 2.5.0 and did NOT happen on GWT 2.4.0. No other changes in code. Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce the problem locally. Both on my local environment and on server machine GlassFish 2.1.1 is used (and I'm stuck with it for now, however if that problem is somehow related to application server, it would still be great to know). The OS on server is Debian Squeeze 64-bit, locally I use Wheezy 32-bit.

In act of despair I added the filter with following code: `httpServletResponse.setHeader("Connection", "close");` but with no result.

Do you have any ideas how to fix that OR how to track which connections are causing problem and when? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, sockets are handled by the browser on the client side and by Glassfish on the server-side, not directly by GWT. Maybe try a thread-dump (ideally when you're sure nobody accesses the server) and see if anyone is stuck in some `com.google.gwt.` class. Also, have a look at https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7779

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: You are right! I've been able to reproduce the problem locally. Thread dump ( http://pastebin.com/rG1b2SF6 ) show that some threads are stuck in com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.SerializabilityUtil. And indeed, the cause is 7779 issue. My other question posted here ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/14346199/545834 ) turns out to be the same problem, just experienced from the other side. Thank you very much, I'll just wait with upgrade to GWT 2.5 until it's fixed (fortunately in the meantime I was able to work around problems with GWT 2.4 - an animation issues in Google Chrome 24).