# GWT 2.5 breaks RPC method - fine on 2.4, but not working after upgrade

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-2.5

After upgrade from GWT 2.4.0 to 2.5.0 only one of many (many!) RPC methods is broken and I have no idea why. Here is what happens (and what does not):

1. The program gets to async service object and calls its method.
2. Underyling, generated by GWT proxy object exists and is called (I don't know its internals, though).
3. The browser doesn't send any request to server (at least developer tools built into Google Chrome doesn't show anything like that happening. On the other hand... see 5.).
4. The implementation on server is never called.
5. If I stop the server, however, `AsyncCallback.onFailure(Throwable)` is executed immediately.

I'll repeat for sake of clarity: **the very same code works like a charm on GWT 2.4.0** and other metods (most of them if not all) work just fine even on 2.5.0.

Now some code. Not sure if necessary, but...

**Async interface**

```
public interface BrokenServiceAsync {
    public void getData(int id, State state, AsyncCallback<Data> asyncCallback);
}
```

Both **State interface** (method param) and it's only implementation are declared in external module (added as jar package). I though this could be the case of that problem, but other methods are using these classes too. And there are no compile-time errors.

**Data** contains a String and an ArrayList of objects subclassing com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModelData. Most other methods use similar objects and it works.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: May be you can attach stacktrace from client ?

Comment: @Igor: That's the problem. There is no exception, thus no stacktrace. It would give some idea what went wrong, but it just hangs silently.

Comment: We have upgraded from 2.4 to 2.5 and no such issues came across. May be the issue has some other cause internal to your coding.

Comment: Have you cleand you Project after update to 2.5? Have you cleand your  browser cache? If not try this.

Comment: @SSR: Other methods are working, so yeah, probably it has to do something with my code. I still have to try rebuilding this call from the scratch and see what happens. With luck I'll stumble on this problem on the way. In that case I'll share here what I discovered. Still, it REALLY should not happen.

Comment: @Sam: That was the first thing to try :) No luck, though.

Comment: Is this in DevMode or prod mode? (or both) Can you use a tool like Wireshark to see what goes on the network? If it fails in DevMode, then run DevMode with the `-gen somefolder` option and add the `somefolder` folder to your source path (if using Eclipse), that way you'll be able to debug step-by-step within the generated proxy class.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: it happens in both modes.  OK, I'll check what happens in network monitor and try to debug it in the suggested way. I use Netbeans, but with luck I'll be able to do that somehow. Thanks for advice!

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: After reading your advice from my other question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345378/gwt-2-5-causes-server-gf-2-1-1-to-hang-multiple-rpc-connections-left-with-cl ) I felt this may be related... and it is! Here is stack dump: http://pastebin.com/rG1b2SF6 I use similar interface/generics setup as in mentioned issue ( https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7779 ) It's definitely the same problem. Thank you!